# Recreating an UTF-8 StreamWriter on an open NamedPipeClientStream causes extra BOM characters on the server

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, utf-8, named-pipes

I have a `NamedPipeServerStream` that stays open, and a `NamedPipeClientStream` that stays open. The `NamedPipeServerStream` has an UTF-8 `StreamReader` that stays open. The `NamedPipeClientStream` has an UTF-8 `StreamWriter` that opens, writes a message, closes and then reopens to write another message. Both the `StreamReader` and the `StreamWriter` are opened with the `leaveOpen` flag set to true, so the `StreamWriter` doesn't close the `NamedPipeClientStream` when it is closed. So far, so good.

I have an issue where from the second time the `StreamWriter` is opened and sends a message, an extra BOM is read by the `StreamReader`. I have managed to recreate it in a small sample program. It is built in .NET 6. This is the code of the sample program:

```
using System.IO.Pipes;

namespace NamedPipeTest
{
    internal class EncodingTest
    {
        private static NamedPipeServerStream namedPipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("mypipe", PipeDirection.InOut, NamedPipeServerStream.MaxAllowedServerInstances, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
        private static NamedPipeClientStream namedPipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "mypipe", PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello! You are the client. Press any key to send a request.");

            Task[] tasks = new Task[]
            {
                Task.Run(() => Server()),
                Task.Run(() => Client())
            };

            Task.WaitAll(tasks);
        }

        static async Task Server()
        {
            if (!namedPipeServer.IsConnected)
            {
                namedPipeServer.WaitForConnection();
            }

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(namedPipeServer, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, false, 1024, true))
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    string? line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Server: Received request: {line}");
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                    {
                        var lineBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line);
                        var possibleBOMString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new byte[] { lineBytes[0], lineBytes[1], lineBytes[2] });
                        if (possibleBOMString.Equals("\uFEFF"))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Server: Whoa, what's up with the extra BOM?");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        static async Task Client()
        {
            if (!namedPipeClient.IsConnected)
            {
                namedPipeClient.Connect(6000);
            }

            while (true)
            {
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(namedPipeClient, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, 1024, true))
                {
                    Console.ReadKey(true);
                    Console.WriteLine("Client: Received key press, sending request.");
                    string? line = "Hello!";
                    await writer.WriteLineAsync(line);
                    await writer.FlushAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Client: Sent request: {line}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
Hello! You are the client. Press any key to send a request.
Client: Received key press, sending request.
Server: Received request: Hello!
Client: Sent request: Hello!
Client: Received key press, sending request.
Server: Received request: ?Hello!
Client: Sent request: Hello!
Server: Whoa, what's up with the extra BOM?
Client: Received key press, sending request.
Server: Received request: ?Hello!
Client: Sent request: Hello!
Server: Whoa, what's up with the extra BOM?
```

And this continues endlessly. So the line does not contain an extra BOM when it is sent, but rather after it has been read by the `StreamReader`. What is happening here?

Comment: Instead of writer.WriteLineAsync(line); use writer.WriteAsync.  It is from the end line marker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` [provides a BOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.utf8?view=net-7.0#remarks)

> It returns a UTF8Encoding object that provides a Unicode byte order mark (BOM).

2. `StreamWriter.FlushAsync` [appends a BOM](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/StreamWriter.cs,944) to the stream.
3. `StreamWriter.Dispose` will call `Flush`, so it also appends a BOM.

The solution is to construct a custom UTF8Encoding object:

```
var enc = new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false);
...
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(namedPipeClient, enc, 1024, true))
```

Comment: This makes sense. However, just skipping flushing didn't change the behavior at all for me (why not, I wonder. Why does it work despite not being flushed? Another matter...), I still get the BOM. Using a custom UTF8Enconding object solved the problem though! I would remove the part with the out-commented Flush call from your answer, and then I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Flushing only writes a BOM if it hasn't already been written, so removing the flush doesn't do anything. The proper solution is to use UTF8 without BOM.

Comment: Please note the order of “using” and “while”, both `Flush` and `Dispose` will append a BOM, so you need to fix both. I assume the order in your question is a typo, because you put "using" outside in the `Server` method.

Comment: No, the order is intentional. As described in the text in my question, the server uses the same StreamReader all the time, while the client recreates the StreamWriter for each request. This is based on context, and the application is of course more complicated than the example I gave, hence the order.

Comment: If the Encoding is not set (null), it uses a UTF8 no-BOM

Comment: But wouldn't that be dangerous to use? What if that changes in the future?

Comment: If this is intentional, you have to use a custom object. I don't think the default encoding will be changed someday, but since you need to pass the next 2 parameters, you can't pass null to the encoding parameter.